# I can not install Bing Search API v7

Tags: azure, bing-api

I can not install Bing Search API v7.

Pricing tier: "no available items"

[image]

Comment: I'm able to see the pricing tiers for Bing Search Resource https://i.imgur.com/glRrzj8.png

Comment: Why is not it possible for me?

Comment: As you can see Pay-As-You-Go Subscription doesn't have pricing tiers - https://i.imgur.com/StxmGVa.png || We need to subscribe to that service!

Comment: You need to register your subscription with `Microsoft.Bing` Resource provider!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Azure Portal,
Go to Subscriptions > Select Your Subscription > Resource Providers > Search for `Microsoft.Bing` and it's status will be unregistered so that Pricing tiers are not visible to your subscription.

[image]

Register that resource provider with your subscription and refresh your browser page (Azure Portal) to get pricing tiers list.