# No Available Pricing Tiers for Pay as You Go

Tags: azure, bing

While trying to set up Bing Search v7 resource, the form fails validation due to empty pricing tier.

However, there are no pricing tiers for me to choose.

[image: creating-bing-search-resource-err]

I am on the `Pay as You Go` offering.

[image]

Comment: This has already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71909532/i-can-not-install-bing-search-api-v7

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you @RimazMohommed